# Error in building opencv with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I installed ffmpeg according to this [article](http://blog.mycodesite.com/compile-opencv-with-ffmpeg-for-ubuntudebian/). ffmpeg installation was ok.
Now I build opencv with ffmpeg support and I have some errors.
The errors are

```
/home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1484:21: error: ‘CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER’ was not declared in this scope
         c->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
                     ^
/home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In function ‘int icv_av_write_frame_FFMPEG(AVFormatContext*, AVStream*, uint8_t*, uint32_t, AVFrame*)’:
/home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1512:30: error: ‘AVFMT_RAWPICTURE’ was not declared in this scope
     if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_RAWPICTURE) {
                              ^
/home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘void CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::close()’:
/home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1686:35: error: ‘AVFMT_RAWPICTURE’ was not declared in this scope
         if( (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_RAWPICTURE) == 0 )
                                   ^
/home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘bool CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::open(const char*, int, double, int, int, bool)’:
/home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1920:32: error: ‘AVFMT_RAWPICTURE’ was not declared in this scope
     if (!(oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_RAWPICTURE)) {
                                ^
In file included from /home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:0:
/home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In static member function ‘static AVStream* OutputMediaStream_FFMPEG::addVideoStream(AVFormatContext*, AVCodecID, int, int, int, double, AVPixelFormat)’:
/home/coie/Softwares/Libraries/opencv-2.4.13.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2214:25: error: ‘CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER’ was not declared in this scope
             c->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
                         ^
modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/build.make:230: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2349: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all' failed
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Same issues with Ubuntu 16.04, ffmpeg from github and opencv 3.3.0.

Comment: @Anonymous yes mine Ubuntu 16.04 and opencv 2.4.13.4. How to solve issue?

Comment: That is the version conflict. OpenCV hasn't updated to match ffmpeg's latest version. I changed to earlier version of ffmpeg from this link (http://ffmpeg.org/releases/) and compiled with --enable-shared flag, now is ok.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

My solution is to grep the missing defines (2 in total) from FFmpeg by using *grep -r* which leads to the following code found in *libavcodec/avcodec.h*:

```
#define AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER (1 << 22)
#define CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER
#define AVFMT_RAWPICTURE 0x0020
```

Copy and paste it to the top of:

```
opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp
```

Compile and everything works even with the latest sources

Comment: Works for opencv 3.2 as well.

Comment: I also needed this for opencv 3.4 on ubuntu 16.

Comment: This may work around the compile error but may introduce a new problem. You need to check if the definition of `AVFMT_RAWPICTURE 0x0020` makes sense in the `OpenCV` code you are building. But if this `videoio` module is not at all your focus, it should be fine to work around the compile error this way.

Comment: works for OpenCV 3.2 on raspi 3+

Answer (score 6):

Easiest change for the CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER is to change it to AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER, it was redefined in a newer version.

Note the "AV_" in front

Answer (score 1):

in opencv:0/2.4 there is no modules/videoio directory! to get that old version (2.4.13-r3) to compile with newest media-video/ffmpeg on gentoo (4.1.3) I had to add above changes to modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_api.hpp with this 
patch:

```
--- opencv-2.4.13/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_api.hpp        2019-05-27 13:28:05.736339890 +0200
+++ opencv-2.4.13-new/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_api.hpp    2019-05-27 13:27:48.787198507 +0200
@@ -12,6 +12,10 @@
 #define OPENCV_FFMPEG_API
 #endif

+#define AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER (1 << 22)
+#define CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER 
AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER
+#define AVFMT_RAWPICTURE 0x0020
+
 enum
 {
     CV_FFMPEG_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC=0,
```

(i.e. I created the path and file /etc/portage/patches/media-libs/opencv-2.4.13-r3/old-ffmpeg.patch with that contents.)
in defense to gentoo, I should mention, the new media-libs/opencv:0/3.4.1 is also available, as is the old media-video/ffmpeg-3.4.5, so I could alternatively also play around with masking out versions or file a bug for developers to do that for me...